# Some work in Python with strings

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
    estructuraDatos = [(here goes the information)]
    for campo in estructuraDatos:
       for x in range(len(campo)):
          print campo[x]
```

and it prints:

```
   000d109e4a25299eeef77a14d6b6a81479d1ac0e
United States
wilco
110
0.016042000875
[['elizabeth mitchell', '0.0482718389966'], ['phish', '0.0274172378591'], ['girl talk', '0.0253755286568'], ['roxette', '0.0245005104273'], ..., ['little feat', '0.00627096397842\n']]
```

How can I do to print it like a table, is it to say:

the id .... the country .... the group ... etc

Where points are spaces

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for campo in estructuraDatos:
    print(' '.join(estructuraDatos))
```

This will loop through the list of lists (I presume) you have and then join the elements with a (space).

Comment: I get a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

Comment: It says TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found

Comment: Show us an example of the data you are passing in.

Answer (score 0):

```
 lst = [['elizabeth mitchell', '0.0482718389966'], ['phish', '0.0274172378591'], ['girl talk', '0.0253755286568'], ['roxette', '0.0245005104273'], ['little feat', '0.00627096397842\n']]  
 >>> def print_nested(lst):
        album = ''
        for each in lst:
            if isinstance(each, list):
                print_nested(each)
                album =''
            else:
                album +=  str(each) + ' '
        print(album)


    >>> print_nested(lst)
    elizabeth mitchell 0.0482718389966 
    phish 0.0274172378591 
    girl talk 0.0253755286568 
    roxette 0.0245005104273 
    little feat 0.00627096397842
```

Recursively calls the function if it encounters a nested list. I don't think the list you had in your question had all the data you wanted in it though.